# Many buttons trigger one modal in html table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

Node express app using EJS.

I'm creating a table - each cell has a button to trigger a modal.  This code is inside a for loop:

```
<td>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <!-- Header-->
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Catalog Numbers</h4>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Body -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <% for(var j = 0; j < user.notifications.length; j++) { %>
                            <%= user.notifications[j] %>
                            <% } %>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Footer -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Subscribed Products </button><br><br>
            </div>
            </td>
```

Every thing loads fine, the rendered html shows that each cell has it's own modal with it's own data but every button triggers `myModal` and they're all called `myModal` so every button loads the modal from the first cell.

Is there a way to dynamically create the `div id` like `myModal1`, `myModal2`, etc.?

I've tried

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%=user.id%> ...>
```

Should I be doing this another way?

Comment: Another way would be to [vary modal content based on the trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

Comment: Thanks for the link, if I'm reading it correctly (I'm new to this) then I can put that script in a `<script>` tag and a button click would trigger that function.  Only thing I'm unclear of is how to display the info that's already rendered in the modal for that buttons cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such would be to use a single modal, but then [vary the modal content based on the trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

What happens is that an event is bound to the modal, which is triggered when the button opens the target modal. You can still hide the modal content inside the table, which the event will find and populate the modal body with.

Here is a simple example which you'll need to adapt to your code:

```js
$(function() {

  // when the modal is shown
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $modal = $(this);

    // find the trigger button
    var $button = $(e.relatedTarget);

    // find the hidden div next to trigger button
    var $notifications = $button.siblings('div.hidden');

    // transfer content to modal body
    $modal.find('.modal-body').html($notifications.html());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Notifications</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>
        <div class="hidden">
          <ul>
            <li>Product one</li>
            <li>Product two</li>
            <li>Product three</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Subscribed Products</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maria</td>
      <td>
        <div class="hidden">
          <ul>
            <li>Product three</li>
            <li>Product four</li>
            <li>Product five</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Subscribed Products</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Header-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Catalog Numbers</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Body -->
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <!-- Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```